# How to Integrate CanvasJS with SQL server using asp.net C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I developed an application that was showing trend of event for period of years and i want to using CanvasJS to visualize the trend.
The Data's are return in a DataTable containing Years and Values. I declare the DataTable as public parameter and convert it to JQUERY String using stringBuilder then pass the Jquery as

```js
datapoints: ['<%=this.mDataTableJquery%>']
```

This did not work for me, i have been on this for three(3) weeks now with no result. I need any technical assistance to get this to work.

Thank you

Comment: I think we'll need more information to provide anything more than hints.  What is the actual problem you're having?  Script errors?  The chart doesn't show up correctly?

Comment: Many thanks, as mention in my earlier question the content of the DataTable was transcripted to JQUERY String so it readable i pass this JQUERY String to the datapoints section of Data unit in the CanvasJS, the result is just a blank slate no chart.

Answer (score 0):

solving this by referencing the Tag
datapoints: ['<%=this.mDataTableJquery%>',datasource]